# Why do I get "Bad option: 'unused'" when I try to apply the 'unused' option in the wro4j jshint plugin (v1.4.7)?

Tags: maven, jshint, wro4j

All the other options I need to use are working nicely but when I add the 'unused' option, I get a complaint when I try either:

```
<options>unused,bitwise,curly,eqeqeq,forin,immed,indent=4,latedef,newcap,noarg,nonew,undef,trailing,onevar,white,browser</options>
```

or

```
<options>unused=true,bitwise,curly,eqeqeq,forin,immed,indent=4,latedef,newcap,noarg,nonew,undef,trailing,onevar,white,browser</options>
```

I get this error:

```
 Errors are: [ro.isdc.wro.extensions.processor.support.linter.LinterError@373246f3[
  line=0
  character=0
  reason=Bad option: 'unused'.
  evidence=
]]
```

I am not sure if I am using incorrect syntax, this option is just not available in this plugin or if this is a bug.

Has anyone else had it working correctly and am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wro4j-1.4.7 uses an older version of jshint (more precisely from [July 06, 2012](https://github.com/alexo/wro4j/blob/v1.4.7/wro4j-extensions/src/main/java/ro/isdc/wro/extensions/processor/support/linter/JsHint.java)), while unused option was introduced since [August 20th, 2012](http://www.jshint.com/changelog/)

If you want to use latest version of JsHint, you can extend the JsHintProcessor and specify the newer version of jshint.js